# Create new object from a given type passed as parameter

Tags: java

I want to create a method in Java that: when I pass a parameter of any a Class type, it creates a new List of that type, acting like generating a dynamic list, then with any other method fill this list (doesn't matter too much) and finally, returning this list filled with elements of this Class type (cast the list).
I want to achieve something moreless this example:

```
public List<fooClass> returnResultsList(Class fooClass) {
     List<fooClass> newList = new ArrayList<fooClass>();
     newList = fillWithResults(); // Pretty sure elements added here are fooClass type.
     return (List<fooClass>) newList;
}
```

I don't know if I have to use reflection.
I've tried doing something like `List<fooClass.class> ....`
Or `List<instanceof(fooClass)> ....`
Or `List<typeof(fooClass)>`
Or `List<fooClass.newInstace()>`
With no success and many compiler errors :(

**EDIT 1:**
Method `fillWithResults()` returns a `java.util.List` object, so it can be cast to any type or class.
In fact, I don't care too much about how this list is filled. The point of the question is how do I create a new object of a Class type passed as parameter.

**EDIT 2:**
I've achieved something like this with no compiler errors, but I'm not pretty sure if it works:

```
public <T> List<T> returnResultsList(Class<T> fooClass) {
    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
    newList = (List<T>) this.fillWithResults();
    // Do something else...
    return newList;
}
```

Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You'll probably have to provide the code for `fillWithResults` to get a complete answer.

Comment: Could your question in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely? Perhaps. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an instance of a class from the class object, you have to use reflection

```
fooClass.newInstance();
Constructor<?>[] constructors   = fooClass.getConstructors();
Class<?>[]       parameterTypes = constructors[ 0 ].getParameterTypes();
constructors[0].newInstance(/*parameters*/);
```

If your just doing the basic constructor then this is easy, if you are using parameters, this becomes very complicated very fast.